# Android camera2 preview does not show

Tags: android, preview, android-camera2

I tried and extended the google CameraTooActivity (which uses a SurfaceView to display the preview). It worked perfectly. However when I incorporated the code into my own app, I always got a blank preview. After much trial and error, I found that I had a 'Z-Order' problem.

After setting the Z-Order for my surface view, I got the preview immediately!

`surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);`

I have added this question (and answer) in the hope that it will save others much time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this is a question with a built-in answer and not proper usage of SO format. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @David, please edit your question so that you can post an answer to it.

Comment: I agree. The question can be closed, because I have answered it myself

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, the answer was to set the Z-Order of the surfaceView with the following:

```
surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```